# Get rendered element height before it shows up on screen (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-redux

I have an animated component that slides up/down depending on the prop (true or false). I'm using **maxHeight: 0** to hide the component (transition is being done with CSS) and that's the default state that's being passed as prop. For the opened style I use a **maxHeight** much bigger than needed just to make sure the content will fit properly. After it's opened I'm able to get its height by ref and set the **maxHeight** accordingly.

```
export default class AnimatedInput extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      height: 600
    }
  }
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    var height = this.refs.inputNode ? this.refs.inputNode.clientHeight : height;
    console.log(height);
    if (this.props.open === false && prevProps.open === true) {
      this.setState({height: height});
    }
  }
  render () {
    var {height} = this.state;
    let test = this.props.open ? 'boxVisible' : 'boxHidden';
    var styles = {
      boxHidden: {
        ...
        maxHeight: 0,
      },
      boxVisible: {
        ....
        maxHeight: height,
      }
    }

    return (
      <div style={styles[test]} ref="inputNode">
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

There are 2 problems with this approach:

1. The first time it's opened and closed is not smooth due to maxHeight being larger than it should (maybe render the opened one off-screen and get its height first?)
2. If it's closed before fully opened the height will be lower than it should (I suppose it's an easy fix - just need to stop updating the height value).

Am I on the right track? How would you fix these? Should I stick to CSS or maybe make the transition entirely in JS. Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `ReactCSSTransitionGroup`. I used this for the exact same thing you are.

Comment: I've stumbled upon it but I wanted to create my own component - guess I'll take a look under its hood. Thanks!